# Call Object's toString() method from .class (Class<?>)

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I have a class named "Test" which I am passing to a method as `Test.class` which will be of type `Class<T> clazz`.

I need to call toString() method of class Test from that clazz variable. Can we do that using reflection without typecasting clazz to Test?

Answer (score 1):

First create object from clazz variable and then called `toString()` Method of that object.

```
clazz.newInstance().toString();
```

If you have a default Constructor then it will also work :

```
clazz.getConstructor().newInstance().toString();
```

**Updated :**
If you want to make general test function then you have to implement test function like this.

```
public void TestToString(Object obj,String expectedVal){
    assertEquals(obj.toString(),expectedVal);
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to typecast it. I want to call it using reflection.

Comment: @The90sArtist see updated answer. you don't need to typecast for calling `toString()` method.

Comment: @The90sArtist: why do you want to force the use of reflection? `toString()` is a method that exist on `Object` so you can just call it on any object without the use of reflection. What advantage do you expect from using reflection?

Comment: I tried above solution, it is still printing com.artist.Test@61a0f38

Comment: @The90sArtist Are you sure you `toString()`function is overriden in `Test` class ?

Comment: But newInstance() will create new Instance of test right? I want to get same object which was given as .class

Comment: @The90sArtist then why you need to pass the .class as aparameter. pass the object to the function.

Comment: Want to make generic function

Comment: @The90sArtist see updated answer for make generic function . pass any object to that function. it will call `toString()` method of that object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call a method on a `Class` parameter.
This is only a description of the class, but to invoke a method you will need an instantiation of the class.
You can:
  - use Reflection to create an instance of the .class parameter to call the method on
**or**
 - use Reflection to call a method on an instance.

But the bottom line is, you ***NEED*** an instance.

Also a little remark (as already stated by Joachim Sauer):
The `toString()` method exists on the `Object` class and everything extends the `Object` class, so it is always available.
There is no need for Reflection, Generics or casting.
You simply override this method in your class and it is good to go.

A little example to demonstrate the different ways to call toString():

```
public class Test {

    private String name = "unnamed";

    public Test() {}

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static <T> T doReflectionCreateToString(Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            T newT = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("Name 2");
            System.out.println("Created by reflection:    "+ newT);
            return newT;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T, E> E doReflectionCall(T obj, String methodName, Object[] arguments, Class<E> returnClazz) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
            Method myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
            return (E) myMethod.invoke(obj, arguments);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> void doGenericToString(T obj) {
        System.out.println("toString by Generic way:  "+ obj);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setName("Name 1");

        System.out.println("toString by standard way: "+ t);

        doGenericToString(t);

        System.out.println("Called by reflection:     "+ doReflectionCall(t, "toString", new Object[]{}, String.class));

        Test newT = doReflectionCreateToString(Test.class);
        System.out.println("Returned by reflection:   "+ newT);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> toString by standard way: Name 1
>   toString by Generic way:  Name 1
>   Called by reflection:     Name 1
>   Created by reflection:    Name 2
>   Returned by reflection:   Name 2

As you can see, whether called the standard way or via Generics or even worse Reflection, all results in the same logic.
I hope this enlightens you (and someone else) ;)